# Проблема с обновлением записи в Active Record

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

Есть страница редактирования новости. Обновляю запись таким образом:

```
$model=News::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);
if(isset($_POST['News'])) {
    $model->attributes=$_POST['News'];
    $model->save();
}
```

Все бы хорошо, вот только есть у меня поле которое содержит изображение. Если же я оставлю пустой форму выбора файла, то значение этого поля перезапишет пустой строкой. Как можно исключить обновление этого поля если я не выбираю файл, те оставить старое изображение?

Comment: В модели `rules` есть строка типа `array('img', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),` ?   То есть разрешает незагруженные фото при апдейте

Comment: 'allowEmpty'=>true  прописано, если без этой строчки, то в случае отсутствия изображения пишет: " Необходимо заполнить поле «Image».", как будто оно обязательное. С     'allowEmpty'=>true     получается отправить форму, но старое изображение перезаписывает пустотой

Comment: `$model = $this->loadModel($id);
$old_img = $model->img;
$model->img = '';
 
if(isset($_POST['News'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['News'];
 
 if(empty($model->img))
      $model->img = $old_img;
   
    $model->save();
}`  попробуйте так

Comment: Можно и так, но этот способ скорее костыль

Comment: Окай, тогда `if(isset($_POST['News'])) { if ($_POST['News']['image']=='')
                            unset($_POST['News']['image']);
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['News'];                        
                        if($model->save()) {...............} }`

Comment: `unset()` не помогает исключить обновление поля `image`, вообще никак не получается обойти его перезапись. Вариант с: `$model->img = $old_img;` тоже как оказалось не подходит, так как мы передаем только имя файла, а ожидается объект изображения. Теперь даже не знаю с какой стороны подойти к решению данной проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему указав какие атрибуты нужно сохранять если не выбрано изображение. Так собственно выглядит код:

```
    if(isset($_POST['News']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['News'];

        // Если выбрано изображение.
        if (!empty($_FILES['News']['name']['image']))
        {
            // Загружаем новое изображение.
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            $path=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/'.$model->image->getName();
            $model->image->saveAs($path);

            // Обновляем запись
            $model->save();
        }
        else
        {
            // Обновляем запись без изображения.
            $model->save(true, array('title', 'desc', 'body', 'alias', 'status')); 
        }
    }
```